# exim4 mail relay for multiple domains

Tags: windows-server-2012, exim, reverse-dns

I have hMailServer running on a Windows 2012 box and exim4 running on a separate box. However, I would like to continue configuring my email accounts on the Windows server (via hMailServer), but relay all outgoing mail through the exim4 server.

The question is... I have several domains configured in hMailServer. How do I configure exim to deliver email for all of those domains?

What i've done so far: 
I've pointed the A records for each domain at the exim server
I've assigned the exim server a hostname of one of my domains, so: mail.mydomain.com (which I don't think is correct)
I've configured hmailserver to point to mail.mydomain.com:25 to send mail. The exim server is indeed listening on port 25.

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated!